# .net 4.5 not working with VS2010, INotifyDataErrorInfo not found

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, .net-4.5

I installed the .net 4.5 framework, but Visual Studio gives the following error
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'INotifyDataErrorInfo' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I modified the project reference paths to the following

C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETCore\v4.5\
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.5\

but then I get the error
error MC1000: Unknown build error, 'Could not load type 'System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter' from assembly 'System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'

Has anyone encountered or resolved this issue before?

Comment: Only by using a very temporary workaround - in the following directory, make a backup of 4.0, and rename the 4.5 directory 4.0 -  C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework    - I made batch files so I could switch between the two - unfortunately when you rename the 4.5 directory to 4.0, you can no longer open native C++ solutions, so I'm constantly switching between the two.

Answer (score 0):

Since .NET 4.5 is still in beta, I think it's only officially supported in the VS11 Developer Preview, not in VS2010.